# Drawing canvas within ImageAnalyzer

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I've got a simple layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#FF000000"
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:4"
tools:context=".pkgActivity.CameraImp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/myP"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:4"
    >

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/preview_area"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no">

    </androidx.camera.view.PreviewView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/foundObject"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pic_desc"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/captureImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:4"
        android:scaleX="-1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/capture"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGalleryImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Gallery" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonChangeCamera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="camera" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGoBackTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="goback" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPaper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="goback" />

 </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: layout]

As you can see I have an `ImageView foundObject` which I want to use to display the border of the found object which I receive from my custom ImageAnalyzer:

```
public class PaperImageAnalyser implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {


    ObjectDetectorOptions options = new ObjectDetectorOptions.Builder()
        .setDetectorMode(ObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
        .enableClassification()  // Optional
        .build();

    ObjectDetector objectDetector = ObjectDetection.getClient(options);



    @Override
    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError") Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();

    if (mediaImage != null) {
        InputImage image =InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees());

        objectDetector.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                new OnSuccessListener<List<DetectedObject>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<DetectedObject> detectedObjects) {
            
                        for (DetectedObject detectedObject : detectedObjects) {
                            Rect boundingBox = detectedObject.getBoundingBox();

                            Log.e("received",""+ boundingBox);
                            Paint paint = new Paint();
                            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                            paint.setStrokeWidth(10f);

                            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
                            canvas.drawRect( boundingBox.left,  boundingBox.top, boundingBox.right,    boundingBox.bottom,   paint   );
                            CameraImp.foundObject.draw(canvas); //CameraImp = my fragment, foundObject is the static imageview

                        }

                    }
                })
            .addOnFailureListener(
                new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e("error",""+e.getMessage());
                    }
                })
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<DetectedObject>>() {
                @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<DetectedObject>> task) {
                    imageProxy.getImage().close();
                    imageProxy.close(); 

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I receive the objects which get recognized for e.g:

```
E/received: Rect(233, 0 - 720, 1309)
E/received: Rect(237, 0 - 720, 1307)
E/received: Rect(235, 0 - 720, 1304)
E/received: Rect(233, 0 - 720, 1303)    
E/received: Rect(229, 0 - 720, 1299)
E/received: Rect(222, 0 - 720, 1293)
E/received: Rect(214, 0 - 720, 1289)
E/received: Rect(207, 0 - 720, 1285)
E/received: Rect(203, 0 - 720, 1285)
E/received: Rect(201, 0 - 720, 1287)
E/received: Rect(201, 0 - 720, 1290)
E/received: Rect(204, 0 - 720, 1294)
E/received: Rect(208, 0 - 720, 1297)
E/received: Rect(210, 0 - 720, 1294)
E/received: Rect(199, 0 - 720, 1271)
E/received: Rect(212, 0 - 720, 1219)
```

but the ImageView dont display the shape of the object.

The question is what the cause is. Is it cause I receive the wrong dimensions from my custom ImageAnalyzer or is it cause I draw the shape wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since the size of the preview and image gets analyzed are different, you will need to get the width and height of the analyzed image and transform the boundingbox to the right size for display. Please refer to this example from mlkit vision_quickstart as a reference. https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/74d5edb101d1e2fb8bd404c41a684b71a06d507a/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/CameraXLivePreviewActivity.java#L421